# Mutate a computed property with in a method in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of year [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]
and I get the index of the current year with this function with a `computed`

```
getSelectedYearIndex(){
  return this.getYears.length - 1
},
```

This function returns 5

Then with a `select` I choose across a new year and receive the new value with an `$emit` in this function in `methods`

```
 onSelect({ selectedIndex }) {
  this.getSelectedYearIndex = selectedIndex
}
```

and nothing happens.

It's there any chance of mutate a computed property?

Comment: This means it's not supposed to be computed in the first place. But this also depends on how it should behave if an array changes.

Comment: Here's the documentation for [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Take note of this statement... _"Computed properties are by default getter-only"_

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use another variable to store the value for the selected index.

```
// Added variable selectedYearIndex
let selectedYearIndex;
getSelectedYearIndex() {
    // Here I set the value of selectedYearIndex if it hasn't been been set yet
    if (this.selectedYearIndex === undefined) {
        this.selectedYearIndex = this.getYears.length - 1;
    }
    return this.selectedYearIndex;
}
```

Then you can set the value of the backing field

```
onSelect({ selectedIndex }) {
   this.selectedYearIndex = selectedIndex
}
```

---

The reason that your assignment didn't do anything is because `this.getSelectedYearIndex = selectedIndex` is turning `this.selectedYearIndex` into a number instead of assigning the value to a variable.